# It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level" in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, .net-3.5

I have to do some changes in a site which was developed by some developer already. On server it was not in built format while it was in code format. I downloaded its copy and try to run it on my machine (I have Win 2003 server) but faced the subjected line. In web.config its authentication mode is form. I am not much experienced and have not used form authentications. I even tried to create a new web site and copy files in it and run it but no luck. Please guide me how I can remove this error.

Answer (score 2):

This error occurs when you have a root web site with a web.config that defines an authentication mode, and a sub-site under that. If for whatever reason a web.config with auth information is created in the sub-site, then you get this error.

For example, it's very common to get this when updating a WCF service reference for a sub-site. The IDE invariably wants to create a web.config file in the project, but once you delete it, the error goes away.

So check that you don't have an extraneous web.config file in any of your sub-sites or sub-projects. If there are any, delete them.